# Save data persistently for every instance of Frama-C

Tags: frama-c

I'm developing an extension to Frama-C, and I intend to create a configuration interface on it.

Is it possible to save states in Frama-C independently of Project or Session, i. e., save a configuration that will be loaded with every instance of it?

I tried with State_builder, but it seems the data is attached to a corresponding project.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you need the following three things:

- the name of the configuration file, e.g. `let config_file () = MyPlugin.Config.file ~error:false "my_plugin.conf"`. See documentation of module `Config` in `plugin.mli` and of module type `Specific_dir` in `parameter_sig.mli`.
- A hook for loading the configuration after the plugin has been loaded: `let () = Cmdline.run_after_extended (fun () -> load_config (config_file()))`. You might want to load the configuration at another stage of Frama-C boot process, as documented in `cmdline.mli`
- A hook for saving the configuration when Frama-C exits: `let () = Cmdline.at_normal_exit (fun () -> save_config (config_file())`

There is an old mechanism, inherited from Cil and used by the GUI to read and write formatted configuration files, found in `cilconfig.mli`, but basically your plugin can choose any format for its own configuration.